# Blank pane on starting Oracle Datamodeler in Fedora

Tags: oracle-sql-data-modeler

When I try to start Oracle SQL developer or Oracle Data modeler from Fedora,a screen opens but it is blank.Any leads here is helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install at least one or both of these. I have them both:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-openjfx
openjfx
```